# How to stack pandas data frame rows into two halves?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, data-science

I am dealing with a data frame with 6 columns, Below is the example df

```
     a   b   c   d   e   f
     1   2   3   4   5   6
     7   8   9   10  11  12
```

Following is the new data frame which I expect:

```
     col1   col2   col3
     1      2      3
     4      5      6
     7      8      9
     10     11     12
```

Please **note** the order of the row elements, **The first row from the original df, becomes the first two rows of the new df, the second row from the original df becomes the next two.**

Please advice me to achieve the required new df.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reshape` the values (which is numpy array) to 3 columns, and construct a new data frame out of it:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 3), columns=["Col"+str(i) for i in range(1,4)])

#Col1   Col2   Col3
#0  1      2      3
#1  4      5      6
#2  7      8      9
#3  10    11     12
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect !!